# Variable explorer in Spyder

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm trying to upload a csv file into python. I have:

```
import numpy

from pylab import *

def load_data(filename='sports_data.csv'):

    import csv

    reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'))
    data_list = []

    for row in reader:
        data_list.append(row)

    return data_list

records=load_data()
print (records)
```

which prints:

```
[['Month', 'NHL: (Canada)', 'MLB: (Canada)', 'NBA: (Canada)', 'NFL: (Canada)'], ['Jan-04', '16', '1', '5', '5'], ['Feb-04', '16', '1', '6', '3'], ['Mar-04', '19', '1', '5', '2'], ['Apr-04', '29', '2', '6', '3'], ['May-04', '16', '2', '6', '2'], ['Jun-04', '11', '2', '7', '2'], ['Jul-04', '6', '2', '5', '2'], ['Aug-04', '6', '2', '4', '4'], ['Sep-04', '10', '2', '3', '9'], ['Oct-04', '7', '4', '5', '8'], ['Nov-04', '6', '1', '8', '7'], ['Dec-04', '7', '1', '7', '8'], ['Jan-05', '6', '1', '7', '8'], ['Feb-05', '8', '1', '8', '4'], ['Mar-05', '4', '1', '7', '3'], ['Apr-05', '3', '3', '7', '3'], ['May-05', '3', '3', '8', '2'], ['Jun-05', '4', '3', '9', '2'], ['Jul-05', '11', '3', '4', '2'], ['Aug-05', '16', '3', '3', '5'], ['Sep-05', '18', '2', '3', '10'], ['Oct-05', '29', '3', '5', '9'], ['Nov-05', '21', '1', '6', '8'], ['Dec-05', '19', '2', '6', '8'], ['Jan-06', '19', '1', '6', '8'], ['Feb-06', '13', '1', '8', '4'], ['Mar-06', '19', '2', '6', '3'], ['Apr-06', '31', '4', '6', '4'], ['May-06', '22', '4', '10', '2'], ['Jun-06', '18', '4', '10', '2'], ['Jul-06', '11', '5', '5', '2'], ['Aug-06', '8', '4', '3', '5'], ['Sep-06', '16', '3', '3', '12'], ['Oct-06', '25', '3', '5', '9'], ['Nov-06', '21', '1', '6', '8'], ['Dec-06', '23', '1', '7', '9'], ['Jan-07', '23', '1', '7', '8'], ['Feb-07', '25', '1', '9', '4'], ['Mar-07', '24', '2', '7', '3'], ['Apr-07', '36', '4', '10', '4'], ['May-07', '20', '4', '9', '2'], ['Jun-07', '14', '5', '7', '2'], ['Jul-07', '11', '4', '4', '3'], ['Aug-07', '9', '4', '3', '5'], ['Sep-07', '20', '4', '3', '12'], ['Oct-07', '25', '4', '5', '10'], ['Nov-07', '22', '1', '7', '10'], ['Dec-07', '22', '1', '7', '12'], ['Jan-08', '22', '1', '7', '9'], ['Feb-08', '26', '1', '9', '4'], ['Mar-08', '26', '2', '7', '3'], ['Apr-08', '36', '5', '8', '4'], ['May-08', '19', '4', '9', '2'], ['Jun-08', '15', '4', '9', '2'], ['Jul-08', '12', '5', '4', '2'], ['Aug-08', '8', '4', '3', '6'], ['Sep-08', '17', '4', '3', '13'], ['Oct-08', '27', '4', '5', '10'], ['Nov-08', '24', '1', '7', '11'], ['Dec-08', '24', '1', '8', '12'], ['Jan-09', '24', '1', '7', '9'], ['Feb-09', '23', '2', '9', '4'], ['Mar-09', '25', '2', '7', '4'], ['Apr-09', '33', '6', '8', '5'], ['May-09', '24', '6', '12', '2'], ['Jun-09', '18', '5', '10', '2'], ['Jul-09', '12', '6', '6', '3'], ['Aug-09', '8', '5', '4', '7'], ['Sep-09', '17', '4', '3', '16'], ['Oct-09', '23', '5', '6', '15'], ['Nov-09', '19', '3', '7', '15'], ['Dec-09', '20', '2', '7', '14'], ['Jan-10', '20', '1', '8', '14'], ['Feb-10', '17', '2', '9', '5'], ['Mar-10', '19', '2', '6', '4'], ['Apr-10', '33', '5', '9', '7'], ['May-10', '25', '5', '11', '3'], ['Jun-10', '17', '6', '12', '2'], ['Jul-10', '10', '6', '9', '3'], ['Aug-10', '9', '6', '5', '7'], ['Sep-10', '14', '5', '4', '17'], ['Oct-10', '25', '6', '8', '16'], ['Nov-10', '22', '2', '8', '16'], ['Dec-10', '23', '2', '9', '15'], ['Jan-11', '30', '2', '8', '14'], ['Feb-11', '31', '2', '11', '5'], ['Mar-11', '30', '3', '8', '3'], ['Apr-11', '48', '7', '10', '4'], ['May-11', '36', '6', '13', '2'], ['Jun-11', '36', '7', '12', '2'], ['Jul-11', '13', '7', '4', '4'], ['Aug-11', '11', '7', '3', '7'], ['Sep-11', '18', '7', '3', '16'], ['Oct-11', '32', '7', '4', '15'], ['Nov-11', '32', '2', '4', '14'], ['Dec-11', '33', '3', '9', '14'], ['Jan-12', '35', '2', '10', '14'], ['Feb-12', '38', '2', '13', '5'], ['Mar-12', '34', '4', '11', '5'], ['Apr-12', '50', '9', '10', '5'], ['May-12', '26', '9', '14', '3'], ['Jun-12', '23', '9', '16', '2'], ['Jul-12', '14', '9', '8', '3'], ['Aug-12', '10', '8', '5', '7'], ['Sep-12', '14', '7', '4', '19'], ['Oct-12', '10', '9', '8', '17'], ['Nov-12', '9', '3', '11', '17'], ['Dec-12', '11', '3', '12', '20'], ['Jan-13', '40', '2', '12', '15'], ['Feb-13', '40', '2', '14', '5'], ['Mar-13', '43', '4', '12', '4'], ['Apr-13', '50', '10', '12', '5'], ['May-13', '52', '9', '13', '3'], ['Jun-13', '33', '12', '16', '3'], ['Jul-13', '17', '10', '6', '3'], ['Aug-13', '9', '8', '4', '8'], ['Sep-13', '20', '5', '4', '22'], ['Oct-13', '37', '6', '7', '18'], ['Nov-13', '32', '2', '9', '17'], ['Dec-13', '32', '2', '10', '18'], ['Jan-14', '35', '2', '11', '14'], ['Feb-14', '22', '2', '12', '5'], ['Mar-14', '37', '3', '10', '4'], ['Apr-14', '47', '8', '16', '4'], ['May-14', '50', '9', '19', '6'], ['Jun-14', '28', '10', '14', '2'], ['Jul-14', '13', '10', '8', '3'], ['Aug-14', '10', '10', '5', '8'], ['Sep-14', '17', '8', '4', '23'], ['Oct-14', '37', '7', '8', '20'], ['Nov-14', '38', '2', '14', '20'], ['Dec-14', '37', '3', '15', '20'], ['Jan-15', '37', '2', '13', '17'], ['Feb-15', '39', '2', '14', '6'], ['Mar-15', '43', '3', '10', '5'], ['Apr-15', '71', '9', '15', '4'], ['May-15', '46', '8', '16', '4'], ['Jun-15', '31', '13', '17', '3'], ['Jul-15', '13', '12', '7', '3'], ['Aug-15', '9', '25', '4', '8'], ['Sep-15', '16', '27', '4', '23'], ['Oct-15', '38', '33', '8', '20'], ['Nov-15', '36', '4', '14', '22'], ['Dec-15', '36', '3', '16', '20'], ['Jan-16', '41', '2', '17', '24'], ['Feb-16', '45', '2', '21', '6'], ['Mar-16', '36', '4', '16', '4'], ['Apr-16', '51', '15', '25', '6'], ['May-16', '39', '15', '45', '3'], ['Jun-16', '34', '17', '32', '2'], ['Jul-16', '13', '22', '10', '3'], ['Aug-16', '8', '23', '5', '7'], ['Sep-16', '13', '25', '5', '24'], ['Oct-16', '38', '30', '10', '21'], ['Nov-16', '40', '6', '19', '20'], ['Dec-16', '40', '3', '20', '21'], ['Jan-17', '44', '2', '20', '22'], ['Feb-17', '43', '2', '22', '7'], ['Mar-17', '53', '4', '21', '4'], ['Apr-17', '99', '13', '33', '6'], ['May-17', '68', '15', '29', '3'], ['Jun-17', '38', '16', '28', '2'], ['Jul-17', '12', '16', '11', '3'], ['Aug-17', '8', '15', '6', '8'], ['Sep-17', '17', '12', '7', '26'], ['Oct-17', '50', '15', '19', '25'], ['Nov-17', '46', '4', '23', '20'], ['Dec-17', '47', '2', '24', '24'], ['Jan-18', '43', '2', '27', '23'], ['Feb-18', '50', '2', '29', '6'], ['Mar-18', '45', '5', '29', '5'], ['Apr-18', '81', '16', '45', '7'], ['May-18', '63', '13', '45', '3'], ['Jun-18', '29', '11', '23', '2'], ['Jul-18', '12', '11', '10', '3'], ['Aug-18', '8', '11', '6', '9'], ['Sep-18', '19', '10', '7', '29'], ['Oct-18', '52', '16', '24', '26'], ['Nov-18', '53', '2', '33', '25'], ['Dec-18', '57', '2', '32', '29'], ['Jan-19', '51', '2', '31', '24'], ['Feb-19', '60', '2', '33', '7'], ['Mar-19', '60', '5', '28', '5'], ['Apr-19', '100', '12', '45', '7'], ['May-19', '51', '11', '70', '3'], ['Jun-19', '36', '11', '66', '2'], ['Jul-19', '13', '12', '16', '3'], ['Aug-19', '8', '13', '6', '10'], ['Sep-19', '19', '10', '6', '33'], ['Oct-19', '53', '17', '19', '27']]
```

I need these values to go in the variable explorer, because I need to slice them into Month / NHL/ MLB/ NFL Lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure What the issue is. Your output looks typical of reading a CSV file a list of lists

```
    data_list =
    [[name1, name2, name3],
    [data1, data2, data3],
    [data1, data2, data3],
    [data1, data2, data3]]
```

It can be sliced vertically:

```
name1_lst = []
for i in data_list:
    name1_lst.append(i[0])
```

Which would give you:

```
    name1_lst = [name1, data1, data1, data1]
```